# Does the existence of irrational numbers like pi prove that infinity exist?

Tags: cosmology, universe

I saw a debate about the universe and how it came about. Some debaters argued that there has to be a beginning because infinity cannot possibly exist. Then someone replied that the fact that some calculations give infinite non-repeating  digits as an answer (for example pi) prove the existence of infinity.

Can someone help me clear this one out? Is this claim true or not?

Comment: ... seems to me that $\pi$ is pretty finite and indeed $\pi<3.15$.

Comment: This is just going to be based on individual opinions, which is off-topic.  I don't think it's even physics in the sense of mainstream physics for this forum.

Comment: I think whether or not $\pi$ has an infinite number of decimal places won't tell you anything about whether the universe had a beginning.

Comment: rational numbers such also have an infinite number of decimal places. They are repeating, but don't see what difference that makes to this particular argument

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411418

Comment: Claim:  Transcendence exists.  Proof: $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: Not that any of this has anything to do with physics, and not that the phrase "infinity exists" has any discernible meaning, but  putting all that aside, if you were trying to prove by example that something is  infinite, why would you point to the decimal expansion of $\pi$ (which is a function from the set of natural numbers to the set of base-10 digits) as opposed to the set of  natural numbers itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a physics question.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri $\pi$ can be constructed from the Peano-arithmetic in not too many steps. We could develop a Turing-machine outputting $\pi$. However, there are countable many Turing-machines, but uncountable many real numbers. Thus, most of the real numbers simply can't be expressed by a finite formula.

Comment: @GNU It seems your question is too philosophical for the flavour of this site. I suggest to re-ask it on the https://philosophy.stackexchange.com . I hope, they won't find it too physical.

Comment: ...seems to me the edit in the title from "infinite" to "irrational" substantively changed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pi$ doesn't prove one way or the other a finite or infinite extent universe.
The universe as we know it is still expanding though at a slower rate than it used to, and will continue to slow. However, the universe is larger than we can accurately measure due to the bending of space across the longitudinal plane. 
The local view we here on earth is one of relative order. However as the field of view is changed from inside the box that most would paint us in, to a view that is able to allow the encompassing known universe as a misshapen bubble that is burgeoning in some areas and imploding a bit in others. 
Point being, it is still growing, not to mention the moving, that is another discussion.

Comment: Actually [the universe is expanding more rapidly than it used to](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2011/press.html).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "However as the field of view is changed from inside the box that most would paint us in, to a view that is able to allow the encompassing known universe as a misshapen bubble that is burgeoning in some areas and imploding a bit in others"?